# vi pasting messes with formatting

Tags: vim, vi

When I opened a vim editor on terminal, I copied the following text to clipboard from another source

```
    int thisVal = findMin(m);
    // System.out.println(val);
    m.add(val);
```

But it becomes

```
                int thisVal = findMin(m);
                // System.out.println(val);
                //                      m.add(val);
```

Why is this case and how to paste correctly with the formatting?
Thank you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
:set paste
```

should cause indenting to work correctly. As uku points out, you can read more information on paste mode using

```
:h paste
```

you can turn off paste mode with

```
:set nopaste
```

Comment: I have this line in my .vimrc, so I can press `F3` to toggle: `set pastetoggle=<F3>`

Comment: so what is going on here? what does this `paste` thing do?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
:set paste
```

Or

```
:set noai
```

Noai (no auto indent) can be again disabled using `:set ai`

Answer (score 1):

In order to permanently save the defined variables:

```
vi ~/.vimrc
```

Add following lines, save & exit

```
:set paste #will enable the paste mode as answered above
:set nu #this will show the line numbers for editor
```

Some Other allowed parameters can be added from the following list:

```
autoindent(ai)
autowrite(aw)
exrc(ex)
errorbells
flash
ignorecase(ic)
lisp
list
magic
modelines
number(nu)
showmatch(sm)
showmode(smd)
wrapscan(ws)
```

Hope this helps to someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple hack, but it works.
S1 : Create your file in <file_name>.txt format
S2 : Paste your code and save
S3 : Rename your file to whatever file format required

Done !